# CompareValidator error message position

Tags: asp.net, compare, validation, comparevalidator

I have CompareValidator control in my webpage and it works perfectly. I use it to validate date which user can enter in textbox. Problem is, that error message is shown in the right of the textbox. Is there any way to show it under the textbox?
Control code is like this:

```
<asp:CompareValidator
   runat="server"
   ID="myValidatorID"
   Type="Date"
   Operator="DataTypeCheck"
   ControlToValidate="DateTextBoxID"
   ErrorMessage="Date is not valid">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<table>

<tr>
<td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBox"/></td>
<td>another control</td>
<td>another control</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><asp:CompareValidator
       runat="server"
       ID="myValidatorID"
       Type="Date"
       Operator="DataTypeCheck"
       ControlToValidate="DateTextBoxID"
       ErrorMessage="Date is not valid">
    </asp:CompareValidator>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<tr>

</table>
```

Comment: But what when it's not the last control in this _line_ and the other controls should not be wrapped?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

It is dynamic validator that show error message on another line.

```
<asp:CompareValidator
   runat="server"
   ID="myValidatorID"
   Type="Date"
   Operator="DataTypeCheck"
   ControlToValidate="DateTextBoxID"
   ErrorMessage="&lt;br /&gt;Date is not valid">
   Display="Dynamic" 
</asp:CompareValidator>
```